# bash output does something to complex variable making it unreadable

Tags: bash

**I have found a solution and will add as a seperate answer**

I have a text file with multiple pairs of values (each value on a separate line), so i am reading and pairing them into a new command.

Line 1 is paired with line 2, line 3 with line 4, etc.

eg a file consisting of similar to the following but 20 times longer

```
0608091bbf8728c0202211c499efc25c395c32621de18fee17fb20d683331022
2
0abb6d087cd5a4cf08eb051ce946482eadb7d3f4549688f2cf7baca5d014bfbc
1
2f1d332abdec0ab4666514cb4f054cfedff800023fc1ab6f8955b248c36512fb
3
```

The expected output is an array that will be accepted.
However the output always fails, the error suggests some loss of format.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2 # first read of a % 2 = 1,
P1='"[{\"txid\":\"' 
P2='\",\"vout\":' 
P3='}]"'

while read p; do 
        a=$((a+1))
        #odd lines are TXID even lines are VOUT
        if ((a % 2 > 0))
            then TXID=$(echo $p)
        else
            VOUT=$(echo $p)
            lockunspent false ${P1}${TXID}${P2}${VOUT}${P3}
        fi
done < out.dat
```

The final output is made up 5 variables, is json form and includes special characters

```
lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"0608091bbf8728c0202211c499efc25c395c32621de18fee17fb20d683331022\",\"vout\":1}]"
```

The returned error is

```
error: {"code":-3,"message":"Expected type array, got str"}
```

**note**

I have also tried sending output to a file, the output is correct as expected and gives correct results when manually copy/pasted from the file.

comm.dat

```
lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"12244d01c4362c3d9319cd8a31b84e8e0763c94750aabe6a2ad64520a241a7af\",\"vout\":1}]"
lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"12244d01c4362c3d9319cd8a31b84e8e0763c94750aabe6a2ad64520a241a7af\",\"vout\":2}]"
lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"1e86de7ecd6e026361cb178d2658665751b76dea2b9b45e7a7871465958191ef\",\"vout\":2}]"
lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"1f443b249a146e55a03cff4ddec666961127d0245ca6d54fdff2a2accfbffda2\",\"vout\":1}]"
etc ....
```

Reading the file with a script gives identical error

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r p; do
    $p
done > comm.dat
```

Comment: Please share sample data with expected output

Comment: i've added sample input, but i'm not expecting output :P just success.
to clarify, doing command manually returns "true"

Comment: `'"[{\"txid\":\"'` do you really mean to double-expand the string? Do you mean to expand and run  `lockunspent false "[{\"txid\"` (ie. `lockunspent false '[{"txid"'`) or `lockunspent false "\"[{\\\"txid\\\"` ? I think you have one level of quoting too much. Does `lockunspent false '[{"txid":"..."}]'` work? You can add `set -x` to your script and inspect the output.

Comment: using -x shows the output to be different to that dumped to file. there is an added single quote . ie lockunspent false '"[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"' vs lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"

Comment: the above might not be clear and i've added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment because I need more reputation)

That error comes from lockunspent, not bash. This is not a bash question, there is something that lockunspent doesn't like. Maybe try without quotation marks? As in:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2 # first read of a % 2 = 1,
P1='[{\"txid\":\"' 
P2='\",\"vout\":' 
P3='}]'

while read p; do 
        a=$((a+1))
        #odd lines are TXID even lines are VOUT
        if ((a % 2 > 0))
            then TXID=$(echo $p)
        else
            VOUT=$(echo $p)
            lockunspent false "${P1}${TXID}${P2}${VOUT}${P3}"
            # or just
            # lockunspent false ${P1}${TXID}${P2}${VOUT}${P3}
        fi
done < out.dat
```

Things in "" are strings. Things between [] are arrays. Maybe that's what it doesn't like.

Comment: I figured it's a bash issue because if I manually copy/paste the output I get expected result. Also those quotations result in the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry, i read that wrong. Lockunspent does require the specific formatting and using the quotes as you suggest actually returns two different errors.

Comment: Might help if you shared those errors? Because that might mean that it actually worked, but you found something else wrong that doesn't have anything to do with the script.

Comment: lockunspent is very picky and running the script with -x shows the addition of single quotes  (i've shown in original question). this is what seems to break it. there may be something in what you are doing to get around this.

Comment: i've found a solution using something very similar to this. will write it up in a bit. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bgdnlp I found some solution. Lockunspent is particularly picky about formatting and I found bash does do some wiggling of special characters in complex variables.

I couldn't get it to work without dumping first to a seperate file. And this works so I'm happy for the moment.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2 # first read of a % 2 = 1,
P1='[{\"txid\":\"' 
P2='\",\"vout\":' 
P3='}]'

while read p; do 
        a=$((a+1))
        #odd lines are TXID even lines are VOUT
        if ((a % 2 > 0))
            then TXID=$(echo $p)
        else
            VOUT=$(echo $p)
            #dump array to new file
            echo "$P1$TXID$P2$VOUT$P3" >> arr.dat
        fi
done < out.dat

while read line; do
        lockunspent false "$line"
done < arr.dat
```

Here's some incidental digging i did to explore how variables were being treated. I really don't know how you'd acheive this without sending to another file.

```
$ lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"
true

$ T="[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"; echo $T; lockunspent false $T
0
error: {"code":-3,"message":"Expected type array, got int"}

$ T='"[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"'; echo $T; lockunspent false $T
"[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"
error: {"code":-3,"message":"Expected type array, got str"}

$ T='"[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"'; echo "$T"; lockunspent false "$T"
"[{\"txid\":\"fd443e2a5490cada3709d550427f7de0d8d70341c07533067462c9a7855d7cd5\",\"vout\":2}]"
error: {"code":-3,"message":"Expected type array, got str"}
```

and some tests using a separate file (similar to my solution).
try to directly read it from the file to a variable, then use it - fail

```
$ c="lockunspent false"; while read line; do $c $line; done < t.txt
error: {"code":-3,"message":"Expected type array, got str"}
```

read from file to a variable, then use variable - fail

```
$ c="lockunspent false"; while read line; do l=$line; done < t.txt; $c $l
error: {"code":-3,"message":"Expected type array, got str"}
```

read from a file, directly use it, then repeat outside loop - fail then success

```
$ c="lockunspent false"; while read line; do $c $line; done < t.txt; $c $line
error: {"code":-3,"message":"Expected type array, got str"}
true
```

also a bunch of trials using "$line" and "$l" that failed.